# PHP combine multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm have the following array.

```
"rent" => array:3 [
        0 => array:1 [
          0 => "5000"
        ]
        1 => array:3 [
          0 => "10000"
          1 => "60000"
          2 => "80000"
        ]
        2 => []
      ]
"house_quantity" => array:3 [
        0 => array:1 [
          0 => "2"
        ]
        1 => array:3 [
          0 => "3"
          1 => "4"
          2 => "6"
        ]
        2 => []
      ]
"property_id" => array:3 [
        0 => 1
        1 => 2
        2 => 3
      ]

"type_of_house" => array:3 [
        0 => array:1 [
          0 => array:1 [
            "type" => "studio_apartment"
          ]
        ]
        1 => array:3 [
          0 => array:1 [
            "type" => "studio_apartment"
          ]
          1 => array:1 [
            "type" => "one_bedroom"
          ]
          2 => array:1 [
            "type" => "two_bedroom"
          ]
        ]
        2 => array:2 [
          0 => array:1 [
            "type" => "studio_apartment"
          ]
          1 => array:1 [
            "type" => "two_bedroom"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

I want to combine the above array so that it forms an array that looks like this.

```
"0" =>  [
        "property_id" => 1
        "type_of_house" => array:3 [
          "type"=> "studio_apartment"
          "rent" => "5000"
          "house_quantity" => "2"
        ]
      ]
"1" =>  [
        "property_id" => 2
        "type_of_house" => array:3 [
          "type"=> "studio_apartment"
          "rent" => "10000"
          "house_quantity" => "3"
        ]
        "type_of_house" => array:3 [
          "type"=> "one_bedroom"
          "rent" => "60000"
          "house_quantity" => "4"
        ]
       "type_of_house" => array:3 [
          "type"=> "two_bedroom"
          "rent" => "80000"
          "house_quantity" => "6"
        ]
      ]
```

So far I'm using the foreach loop to loop over the properties and attach the type of houses in each of those properties as follows:

```
  foreach ($request->property_id as $key=> $property_id) {
            $result[$key] = array(
                'property_id' => $property_id,
                'type_of_house' => $request->type_of_house[$key]
            );
            foreach ($result as $property_key => $property) {
                foreach ($property['type_of_house'] as $house_key => $house) {
                    $house[$key][$house_key] = array(
                            'rent' => $request->rent[$key][$house_key],
                            'house_quantity' => $request->house_quantity[$key][$house_key]
                        );
                }
            }
        $merge = array_merge_recursive($result, $house);
        dd($merge);
        }
```

But the array I'm getting back is not quite right. This is the array that I'm getting back.

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "property_id" => 1
    "type_of_house" => array:1 [
      0 => array:1 [
        "type" => "studio_apartment"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "type" => "studio_apartment"
  1 => array:1 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "rent" => "5000"
      "house_quantity" => "2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

How do I correctly merge such an array, thanks.

Comment: You _start_ with a _proper_ explanation of the logic by which you want to merge this data, instead of _just_ pointing to the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's suppose you have 2 arrays

`$array1`:

```
Array(2){
    [number] => 1,
    [address] => "Park Ave 273",
    [name] => "Peter Jones"
}
```

And then a clean `$array2`, the one i'm gonna be putting my info
To mix them i would have to specify the index i want the first array to get in, for example:

```
$array1 = array(
        "number" => 1,
        "address" => "Park Ave 273",
        "name" => "Peter Jones"
    );
    $array2 = array();
    $array2['client'] = $array1;
```

Would return:

```
Array
(
    [client] => Array
        (
            [number] => 1
            [address] => Park Ave 273
            [name] => Peter Jones
        )

)
```

In case you have more than one client (on this example) you have to do a `foreach` loop for every client.